# How can I set the prompt for remote MySQL clients?

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface

I'd like to customize my MySQL command-line prompt for any remote clients connecting to a particular server. Something like `LIVE SERVER DON'T DO ANYTHING STUPID>`.

I know I can set an [option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_prompt) in the various `my.cnf` files for a MySQL client so that the prompt is customized, but I believe that would have to be done on any client that might want to connect. The "server" doesn't seem to support that option. I'd prefer that *every* client that connects get that prompt.

Is that kind of thing possible? If so, how?

Comment: I doubt it, and it wouldn't be effective on non-CLI clients like Sequel Pro or phpMyAdmin anyways. You're probably better off limiting access to people less likely to `TRUNCATE users` without thinking it through.

Comment: @ceejayoz Oh, we have the proper `GRANT`s established... it's just that a legitimate user can still sometimes forget they are working in production. :)